# How to SEO optimise Ajax/Json loaded images?

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo

I am using Galleria.io on a website to display a gallery of images. In the database, the images have a title and description to properly explain what the image is.

I load the images into galleria using `dataSource` and a Json array. The gallery works fine and shows the title and description in the gallery however no keyword analyzer picks up the content of the title and description as the images are loaded at run time.

What would be the best way of making the title and description available for a search engine to crawl while associating it to the appropriate images?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest would be to add an image sitemap:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/adding-images-to-your-sitemaps.html

The idea of a sitemap is to help Google with uncrawlable content.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the Fetch as Googlebot tool, are the images visible?

Google is pretty good at working with Ajax and similar, but not perfect.

The best method is to display the images right in the code of the page using good old HTML if possible...

Answer (score 0):

This might be something to look into further as well. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: While this link may help answer the question, a link only answer is not high quality.   You should include the important information from the link here as well.   The content at the link may change or even disappear.   In addition, it is more useful not to force the user to click to get an answer.